# Clone win 10 with tpm and bitlocker to bigger disk

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, clonezilla, tpm, dualboot

I got a new PC for a job, the situation is that I'm not a windows administrator and I have several limitation in using needed software without admin rights.

the volume is encrypted with bitlocker, I suppose the bitlocker key is stored into the TPM chip, and I have the bitlocker key.

Since on the system some software are needed like 1 time every month, but I cannot install them on a brand new windows installation ( they do not work if the machine is not domain-joined and also other checks that I do not know)  I would like to:

- Buy a new NVME with doubled space
- clone the current disk into an image and restore it to the new one
- Install a new windows 10 on the unallocated space in dual boot with the old installation.

I'm not very confident with TPM, Bitlocker and cloning solutions in the new era, but I suppose I can clone the disk to an image with software at boot like Clonezilla in sect to sect mode and restore it on the new disk. I would like to have an advice in general and specially for the TPM, It will recognize and unlock the new volume or it is hardware linked to the disk specs?

any advice is very welcome!

Comment: Why don’t you get the Administrator to do all this work?

Comment: @Ramhound unfortunately the helpdesk is slowed down,  anyway they provide single installation   for the software that require admin rights from remote, let's tell that they do not permit the execution of software that need admin rights generic, I need to create and manage some vms to test but I cannot install hyper-v or anyother software, its funny because I have to manage the customer infrastrutturead, and I cannot use powershell due to the  os restriction. My collegues has another install of windows since they do not have bitlocker on their volumes. I w to know Also for Personal knowledge.